# Implementation of AKS primality test in Scheme or C++

Tags: c++, scheme, implementation, primality-test

I was reading about the prime test algorithm and found the [AKS primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test). Could this algorithm be implemented in [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29) or in C++?

Has anyone tried implementing the AKS test?

Comment: google, first hit with "AKS c++"

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question to: "Has anyone tried implementing the AKS test?"

Answer (score 5):

Scheme and C++ (and Racket and Pascal and Logo and Modula-3 and Postscript) are all Turing equivalent, meaning that they can all be used to simulate each other, and hence that they can all compute the same things.

So: yes, you can implement this in Scheme. Or any other Turing-complete language.

Comment: Thank you. It's so frustrating when people ask if X can be implemented in language Y without realizing that the answer is always yes for any Turing-complete language.

Comment: :D Thats a good answer. Excuse me, i'm new in this kind of things, be tolerant @pg1989.

Comment: No worries. Everyone starts from 0.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it can. Google helps here.

[C++ implementations](http://yves.gallot.pagesperso-orange.fr/src/)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, here is some documentation:  http://ece.gmu.edu%2Fcourses%2FECE746%2Fproject%2FF06_Project_resources%2FSalembier_Southerington_AKS.pdf